# Concatenate Threads for acquiring and showing or saving frames

Tags: python, multithreading, image, save, tiff

How can we concatenate two Threads consecutively? the idea would be to have a Thread capturing images from a camera and when the frame is ready, save it in the disk with another Thread. The problem is that the saving part normally is limiting the frame rate since it is quite blocking. I am running the two threads one after the other, but only the first image is saved. Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be to save frames (from both Threads) in a global list. Then, in your `main` function save the frames in list **after** joining both threads. Something like this:

```py
frames = []

thread1.run()
thread2.run()
...
thread1.join()
thread2.join()

saveFiles(frames)
```

Comment: What I am doing is creating a thread for getting the frame and another thread for saving it in the disk. I posted the code in another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62660281/using-multithreads-for-reading-and-saving-frames-for-a-camera-in-python( i wrote a wrapper for the camera, that is not included). Maybe should I put the .join() somewhere in my class?

Comment: Referring to your original question, I believe `save` is not working because you are overwriting the same file. You are setting the filename = `os.path.join(self.folder,(str(self.counter)+'.tiff'))` and `self.counter` never changes in `VideoSave()`. Therefore, it will keep overwriting the same file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. My idea is that the self.counter is an input of the VideoSave() class because needs to be updated for each frame that is acquired during my VideoGet() class. My knowledge about Thread is limited but I guess I am actually saving the first frame and the rest of the frames don't even enter on the save method, that is why i am trying to figure out how to save the frame when it is acquired, but without blocking the next frame

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use **producer-consumer pattern** for "concatenating" between threads.

Simple example with slow consumer:

```
import queue
import threading
import time

orders = queue.Queue(maxsize=10)


def consumer():
    while True:
        new_order = orders.get()
        if new_order is None:
            break
        time.sleep(1)
        print(f"{new_order} processed")


def producer():
    for i in range(20):
        orders.put(f"Order{i}")
        print(f"Order{i} enqueued")
    orders.put(None)


prod_thread = threading.Thread(target=producer)
con_thread = threading.Thread(target=consumer)
prod_thread.start()
con_thread.start()
prod_thread.join()
con_thread.join()
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for the input, is quite useful, maybe the threads need to be daemon=True for not falling in an infinite loop?

Comment: I don't think you need a daemon thread. `None` sentinel works well in my simple case. If it doesn't work for you, likely you have a mistake

Comment: Before i had an infinite loop. (i put the comment below), but them i added at then end            prod_thread.daemon=True,
con_thread.daemon=True and seems to work. The problem is that the producer is defined ( for 20 in your case) but I would need to keep producing frames until i send a command to stop it ( that self.stopped commented below). does this configuration only work for pre-defined for-loops producers?

Comment: Your producer can send `None` after stop flag is true or your consumer can check stop flag also.